# Creating a Simple Title Screen?

Tags: python

I'm doing this simple game in Ren'Py,

```
# Scarlet Mansion Library
# A Game by fujiyama-volcano
# Curated and designed by fujiyama-volcano
# with additional support by sharksfan98
# (c)2013 using MIT License
# https://github.com/fujiyama-volcano/Scarlet-Mansion-Library

# You can place the script of your game in this file.

init python:
    def callback(event, **kwargs):
        if event == "show":
            renpy.music.play("godawful-beeping-noise.ogg", channel="sound")
        elif event == "slow_done" or event == "end":
            renpy.music.stop(channel="sound")

init python:
    def stats_frame(name, level, hp, maxhp, **properties):

        ui.frame(xfill=False, yminimum=None, **properties)

        ui.hbox() # (name, "HP", bar) from (level, hp, maxhp)
        ui.vbox() # name from ("HP", bar)

        ui.text(name, size=20)

        ui.hbox() # "HP" from bar
        ui.text("HP", size=20)
        ui.bar(maxhp, hp,
                xmaximum=150,
                left_bar=Frame("rrslider_full.png", 12, 0),
                right_bar=Frame("rrslider_empty.png", 12, 0),
                thumb=None,
                thumb_shadow=None)

        ui.close()
        ui.close()

        ui.vbox() # Level from (hp/maxhp)

        ui.text("Lv. %d" % level, xalign=0.5, size=20)
        ui.text("%d/%d" % (hp, maxhp), xalign=0.5, size=20)

        ui.close()
        ui.close()

# Declare images below this line, using the image statement.
# eg. image eileen happy = "eileen_happy.png"

# Declare characters used by this game.
define f = Character('Fujiwara',color="#9F1D35")

define y = Character ('Yukko',color="#00A86B")

define speed = DynamicCharacter(passerby_boy)

    $ narrator = Character(None, window_left_padding=160)

scene black with dissolve

show text "Chapter 1\nA Frightening Sight" with Pause(1.5)

scene black with dissolve

scene your_scene_title

e "And now the story really begins."


    # The game starts here.
       label start:

    $ "H-hey..."

    $ "(Why is it so dark? {w}It's 15:00, isn't it?)"

    $ "What should I do about this situation?"

    menu:
    $ "Light a match."
       jump burn

    $ "Sit down."
       jump splash

       label splash:

    $ "Crud!\nI fell into the fountain...{w}(But is it really a fountain? It could be a lake or something)."
         jump speed

    $ passerby_boy = "???"

         label burn:

    $ "Ack! I burned my hand!"

    $ "Wow, this will be the best day of my entire life!\n(Not.)"

    $ "I guess I could just blindly wander through .\nHere I go!"
         jump splash

         label speed:
      play sound "sfx-thud.wav"

    speed:"Yo, watch it!"

   stop sound "sfx-thud.wav"

    speed: "You can't just barge into people like that, moron."

    $ "Who the heck are you?"

    speed: "The name's /Speed/."

    $ "(Poor guy.)"

    speed:"And you shouldn't have done that..."

    $ "(I think I should get something to defend myself with...)"

    menu:
    $ "A sword!"
    jump dark

    $ "Magic!"
    jump battle1

    label dark:

    "You picked the sword, but realize it's much too dark to use it.\nYou decide to use your magic to fight this guy."

    jump battle1

    label battle1:

    $ "This should be easy! \nI have 150 HP at the beginning of the game!"   

          python:
        charmax_HP = 150
        char_HP = 150

        speedmax_HP = 85
        speed_HP = 85




    return
```

Can somebody find me and help me with a small title screen template? I want it to include a "Start Game" option, "Options" tab with volume and full screen option, and a Load/Save option. Thanks!